# Was it ok to swear in 1 Corinthians 15:31?

Tags: matthew, 1-corinthians

Matthew 5:34
But I tell you, do not swear an oath at all: either by heaven, for it is God's throne;

1 Corinthians 15:31
For I swear, dear brothers and sisters, that I face death daily. This is as certain as my pride in what Christ Jesus our Lord has done in you.

Jesus said not to swear and then Paul did. Why?

Comment: Paul swears (or guarantees) by his own reputation among believers (which would otherwise have been lost anyway); Christ said not to swear on God, or on the symbols of his power (heaven and earth), or on holy things (Jerusalem), or on something that might in any way jeopardize our life or health (our head).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is simple.

Jesus' injunction in Matt 5:34 **not** to swear (ie, solemnly affirm with an oath on something sacred) is quite valid.  The text in 1 Cor 15:31 is an unfortunate translation - the Greek contains nothing about "swearing" or oaths.  Here are some other versions more faithful to the original Greek:

- NIV: I face death every day--yes, just as surely as I boast about you in Christ Jesus our Lord.
- ESV: I protest, brothers, by my pride in you, which I have in Christ Jesus our Lord, I die every day!
- BSB: I face death every day, brothers, as surely as I boast about you in Christ Jesus our Lord.
- BLB: I die every day, as surely as the boasting in you, brothers, which I have in Christ Jesus our Lord.
- NASB: I affirm, brethren, by the boasting in you which I have in Christ Jesus our Lord, I die daily.
- CSB: I face death every day, as surely as I may boast about you, brothers and sisters, in Christ Jesus our Lord.
- HCSB: I affirm by the pride in you that I have in Christ Jesus our Lord: I die every day!

... and so forth.